# How to iterate through collection in JSP and set values in an object in an action class

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, ognl, indexed-properties

I have a JSP that receives a collection list from an action class. I am iterating through that list and I wish to set the values of that list to another object inside another action class through a form request.  When I use the displayMovies.jsp when I use the `<s:property`tag in the iterator it displays on the different objects in the collection. I want to save or pass each of those objects in the collection to a different action class.

**displayMovies.jsp**

```jsp
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1" import="com.sans.model.Movie"  %>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

Movie retrieval Page
<br />
<s:iterator value="movieRetrievedArray" var="movieS">

<s:form action="movieDetails.action" method="post" id="movieDetailsForm">
    <s:property value="title"/><br />
    <s:property value="releaseDate"/><br /> 

    <s:hidden name="movieDetailedInformation.title" value="%{title}" id="hiddenMovie" />

    <img  src="<s:property value="posterPath" />" onClick="test()">
</s:form>
    <br />
    <br />
</s:iterator>

<script type="text/javascript">

function test() {
    document.getElementById("movieDetailsForm").submit();
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

**MovieDetailsActions.java**

```
package com.esi.actions;

import java.util.Map;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import org.apache.struts2.ServletActionContext;
import org.apache.struts2.convention.annotation.Action;
import org.apache.struts2.convention.annotation.Result;
import org.apache.struts2.convention.annotation.Results;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionContext;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;
import com.sans.model.Movie;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Results({
    @Result(name="success", location="/RetrieveMovies/movieDetails.jsp"),
    @Result(name="input", location="/RetrieveMovies/movieError.jsp")
})
public class MovieDetailsAction extends ActionSupport {

    private Movie movieDetailedInformation = new Movie();

    @Action(value="movieDetails")
    public String execute() {


        System.out.println(movieDetailedInformation.getTitle());


        return SUCCESS;
    }

    public Movie getMovieDetailedInformation() {
        return movieDetailedInformation;
    }

    public void setMovieDetailedInformation(Movie movieDetailedInformation) {
        this.movieDetailedInformation = movieDetailedInformation;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `status` variable on iterator tag.

```jsp
<s:form action="movieDetails.action" method="post" id="movieDetailsForm">
<s:iterator value="movieRetrievedArray" var="movieS" status="status">    
    <s:property value="title"/><br />
    <s:property value="releaseDate"/><br />     
    <s:hidden name="movieDetailedInformationList[%{#status.index}].title" value="%{title}" id="hiddenMovie" />
    <br />
    <br />    
</s:iterator>
    <img  src="<s:property value="posterPath" />" onClick="test()">
</s:form>
```

The `movieDetailedInformationList` is

```
private List<Movie> movieDetailedInformationList;

public List<Movie> getMovieDetailedInformationList() { return movieDetailedInformationList; }
```

You don't need to initialize `movieDetailedInformationList`, because Struts2 populate it with parameters from the post request.

The `Movie` class should be public and have default constructor, the public setter for `title` is necessary.

Comment: I've tried that and its almost working, but it's always passing the title of the first index(0) object everytime

Comment: It's ok, don't use negative indexes.

Comment: sorry i don't understand what you mean by don't use negative indexes?

Comment: I mean zero index is a valid index for lists, but negative indexed aren't valid.

Comment: Oh that I know already.  What I initially wanted to do was that because I'm using an iterator to iterate over the collection with form tags inside.  I wanted each form to pass back its equivalent iterator index.  But every form I click is always passing a 0 instead of the incremented value.

Comment: You should use only one form, the index is stored to the parameter name from the iterator status, so it does not depend on form.